# PHP alternative syntax and string/number comparison

Tags: php, string, syntax, numbers

I can go out of this. Normal syntax seems to work, otherwise alternative syntax seems not to work as expected.

```
<?php
$num =  "abcdefghi";

function checkNum($n) {

    if(!is_numeric($n))
    {
        return "not numeric";
    } else
    {
        if($n<0)
        {
            return "less than zero";
        } else
        {
            return "greater then or equal to zero";
        }
    }
}

echo checkNum($num); # echoes "not numeric";

function checkNum2($n)
{
    $r = !is_numeric($n) ? "not numeric" : $n<0 ? "less than zero" : "greater then or equal to zero";
    return $r;
}

echo checkNum2($num); # echoes "less than zero"
?>
```

So what's the problem?

Thankyou in advance.

Comment: Just because a string contains a numeric value, you might still want to explicitly cast it to float otherwise it will be treated as an integer in your subsequent comparisons

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this, you just missed `()` in your function.

```
function checkNum2($n)
{
    $r = !is_numeric($n) ? "not numeric" : ($n<0 ? "less than zero" : "greater then or equal to zero");
    return $r;
}

echo checkNum2($num); # echoes "not numeric";
```

working example http://codepad.viper-7.com/DVvQaC

Comment: Damn! ...parentheses... :-) Thankyou!

Comment: @Nineoclick Marking the answer as correct is good habit if it has solved your problem. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
$r = (!is_numeric($n)) ? "not numeric" : (($n<0) ? "less than zero" : "greater then or equal to zero");
```